# React useEffect is late runnig

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a state map. map contains coordinates and goes to react-leaflet as props. I am updating the map using useEffect, but it works late, the inital value is gone as props.

```
const [map,setMap] = useState([0,0]);

useEffect(() => {
  const data = getIp();
  data.then(result => {
    setMap([result.lat,result.lon]);
  })
},[])

console.log(map);
```

console.log view:

```
Array [ 0, 0 ]
Array [ 36.8943, 30.7209 ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--if it's running an async function ot takes time and is unlikely to resolve befote the first render, like any other async function.

Comment: It's normal, you should use a spinner (loading) to wait data to come.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

useEffect hook is running after the first render so if you want to avoid the first render you could use a loader in your state and use it to conditionally render the content:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

const [map,setMap] = useState([0,0]);

useEffect(() => {
  const data = getIp();
  data.then(result => {
    setMap([result.lat,result.lon]);
    setLoading(false);
  })
},[])

if (loading) return <p>Loading</p>;

return (
    ...your code
);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to React documentation : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

> By default, effects run after every **completed render**, but you can
> choose to fire them only when certain values have changed.

So your useEffect will work after the first render, that's normal behaivor.